# Как обновить страницу?

Tags: javascript

Имеется первая страница, из нее открывается вторая, использующая некоторые переменные первой, со второй страницы открывается 3я страница, которая использует переменные второй, в момент открытия 3й страницы, вторая закрывается. 3я страница сабмитится и закрывается.

Вопрос, как по закрытию 3й страницы заставить обновляться самую первую?
Страницы открываются через window.open(), и им присваиваются имена, все переменные передаются через url по принципу get.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать так, но это работает если у вас все на одном домене:

Есть у sessionStorage событие реагирующее на изменение данных в sessionStorage. Она работает на всех открытых страницах с доступом к storage.

```
window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);

function storageEventHandler(e){
    location.reload();
}

sessionStorage.setItem("someKey", "someValue");
```

Пример: http://html5demos.com/storage-events

Т.е. если мы изменим значение в sesstionStorage на одной странице - на другой странице произойдет событие и мы, кстати, сможем через него передать параметры.

Answer (score 0):

сделайте редирект на первую с новыми параметрами

Comment: Очень не хотелось бы закрывать первое окно браузера, чтобы потом заново его открывать редиректом, тем более, 2 и 3 окна, открываются со специфическими параметрами, своими размерами и прочее. необходимо именно обновить первое.